# Pull specific data from two columns in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

[image]

I have the above table and I need to count the tickets based on their priority and status.
Priority and status are columns G and F in a separate sheet.

I could not find a formula to pull the data for example: how many Highest priority tickets that are closed, I have

I tried a number of formulas, filtering and query but they did not work

```
=FILTER(F:F, G:G="Waiting on Customer", F:F=MAX(F:F))

=QUERY(A1:G, "SELECT F, G WHERE G = 'Waiting on Customer' ORDER BY F DESC LIMIT 10", 1)
```